Show Galois Group of a polynomial is isomorphic to $S_n$
We just moved on from Galois theory to solving polynomial equations and I don't quite understand a problem we were given:

Let $p \geq 5$ be prime and $0 < a_1 < ... < a_{p-2}<b$ be even integers. Consider the polynomial $f(x)=(X^2+b)(X-a_1)...(X-a_{p-2})-2 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$. Show that the Galois group $G$ of $f$ is isomorphic to $S_n$.

For this, I am given two hints:

Show that f has $p-2$ real roots over $\mathbb{C}$

and

Show $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

The only thing I know is that for a separable polynomial $f$, its Galois group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$.
I think I somewhat understand the hints, although I do not know how to prove them.

If $f$ has $p-2$ real roots over $\mathbb{C}$, the same must hold for its splitting field. Since the remaining roots must be complex they also have to be different otherwise we would obtain another real root (is this true?).

If the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ then its Galois group is transitive on its roots (is this true?).


In my opinion the first hint would then give me separability, while I would somehow have to use the second one to argue that it must already hold that $G \cong S_n$?
However, I am completely lost on the details because this is all very new to me so I would appreciate any advice you guys can give me on this.

I'm assuming you already proved that $f$ is irreducible and has exactly two non-real roots over $\mathbb C$. Since it is irreducible, the size of the Galois group of $f$ is divisible by $p$ and by Sylow's first theorem it has en element of order $p$. By the conjugate root theorem, the two non-real roots of $f$ are complex conjugates of each other, therefore $z\mapsto \overline z$ is an element of the Galois group and it has order 2. There's a lemma in group theory that says that a subgroup of $S_p$ ($p$ prime and odd) that contains an element of order 2 and an element of order p is the entire $S_p$ and you're done.

You mean the Galois group has an element of order $p$. It would be worth going into more detail about this argument and in particular the way it depends on $p$ being prime.
